# Starting a sentence with "If making ..."

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrases, verbs

How do constructions of the type *If + verb(-inf form)*

> If making the right choice ...

seem to native English speakers? Some suggested to avoid such constructions and use instead, "If we make the right choice ...".

What do you think? There are many such examples not only at the beginning of the sentence.

Any advice (on the usage of such forms) will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, 135. 'If making a good impression on other partygoers is seen as a priority, then by all means ...' is totally acceptable. However, 'If making the right choice, we can avoid a lot of problems' in place of 'If we make the right choice, we can avoid a lot of problems' is, if not downright ungrammatical, then stilted, rather less clear, and unidiomatic. // 'If making the right choice, he still went on to lose a lot of popularity' in place of '[Even] if he was here making the right chouce, he still went on to ...' is slightly better. // 'By making the right choice ...' works fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely sentences where "If making the right choice..." could not be replaced with "If we made the right choice..." or any similar construct.

> If making the right choice came naturally to him he would not have to spend so long considering things.

"Making the right choice" is a perfectly valid noun phrase and sentences can correctly be written about it.